# Adding TinyMCE to my dynamic form table

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I had an idea to help me work better and create tools for myself to work faster.
I intend to make documents to save my QA work to the db and to my server.
All that works so far on my local, but the problem im sitting with is that the TinyMCE editor i want to use is not working.

I have a dynamic table added to my form that helps me add and delete rows in my form. In one of the columns i have added the TinyMCE editor in to describe the process i did with my qa testing. I have added the tag "", but when i want to add another row, the editor has stopped working. I would like to know what can i do to create a new row but still be able to have the editor work in eack column/ row

```
<fieldset class="row2">
                <legend>Process</legend>
                <p> 
                    <input type="button" value="Add Row" onClick="addRow('dataTable')" /> 
                    <input type="button" value="Remove Row" onClick="deleteRow('dataTable')"  /> 
                    <p>(All acions apply only to entries with check marked check boxes only.)</p>
                </p>
               <table id="dataTable" class="form" border="1">
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <p>
                        <td><input type="checkbox" required="required" name="chk[]" checked="checked" /></td>
                        <td>
                            <label>Name</label>
                            <input type="text" required="required" name="BX_STEP[]">
                         </td>
                         <td>
                            <label for="BX_process">Age</label>
                            <textarea type="text" required="required" class="small"  name="BX_process[]"></textarea>
                         </td>

                         <td>
                            <label for="BX_pass-fail">Gender</label>
                            <select id="BX_pass-fail" name="BX_pass-fail" required="required">
                                <option>....</option>
                                <option>Pass</option>
                                <option>Fail</option>
                            </select>
                         </td>
                        <td>
                            <label for="BX_comment">Berth Pre</label>
                            <input id="BX_comment" name="BX_comment" required="required">
                         </td>
                        </p>
                    </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </fieldset>


<script src="//tinymce.cachefly.net/4.2/tinymce.min.js"></script>
    <script>tinymce.init({selector:'textarea'});</script>
```

I would just like to know how to generate a new text editor for every row i add?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to initialize each of the `textarea`s independently. For example:

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({selector:'#ta1'});
    tinymce.init({selector:'#ta2'});
</script>
<h1>My First Text Area</h1>
<textarea id="ta1">Hello! Look at me, I'm an editable textarea!</textarea>
<h1>My Other Text Area</h1>
<textarea id="ta2">Whoa! Now there are two of us!</textarea>
```

See my jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wr8rh6b8/

You might also want to read up on selectors. The same selector syntax is used for CSS and for identifying DOM elements from your JavaScript code. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors

Comment: Hi Sir! The selector works fine. What im trying is in the data table (this table is dynamic. I add and remove rows as i wish), I want to add a new textarea to every row. I think i would need to generate a new 'id' for every row added and save it that way. Ive looked everywhere for it but i cant seem to track one. What i was thinking, Should i not rather just add or use a mini markdown to it. and step away from the editor. I will be the only one using this form, and in the end the mini markdown will display the data entered the same?